# Typo3 8.3.1 Could not access remote resource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz

Tags: php, xampp, windows-10, typo3

I cannot upate the extension list in TYPO3. This is the error he gives me:

```
Could not access remote resource http://repositories.typo3.org/mirrors.xml.gz.
```

I am running Windows 10.
TYPO3 8.3.1 running on XAMPP v3.2.2 (PHP 7.0.9)

I tried several things, from editing the php.ini to editing the httpd.conf but nothing worked for me.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Can you open the URL in a browser? It should download a small .gz file of a few hundred bytes. Please check if there are no firewall restrictions for apache on your system.
If you have `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['curlUse']` then make sure cURL is configured correctly. Otherwise it uses `file_get_contents()` to fetch the file. Make sure all the wrappers are working. You could make a small PHP test script that tries to fetch the URL you mentioned to see if there are problems in your PHP configuration.

Comment: PHP on windows doesn't trust any certificate authorities, doesn't it?

Comment: Because that URL should be automatically redirected to HTTPS from the server side.

Comment: @StephenKing, I run various TYPO3 dev versions on Windows 10 with XAMPP 1.8.3 (XAMPP Control Panel version is 3.2.1), PHP 7.0.3 without any problems. I do run MySQL and Apache as services.
No issues with downloading the mirror file or the TER extension list file.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and found a solution in this (german) comment here:
https://www.pagemachine.de/blog/wie-ihr-typo3-8-0-als-lokales-testsystem-unter-windows-installiert-unser-tutorial/#div-comment-4718

You have to download and save this file: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem .
Then open your php.ini and enter the absolute path to this file for the option "curl.cainfo". So you have something like

```
curl.cainfo = C:\xampp\cacert.pem
```

There should be already a line ";curl.cainfo =", be sure to remove the semicolon in front to activate the option.

I just did this with TYPO3 8.7.0 and XAMPP 3.2.2 (PHP 7.0.15) and it worked immediately after restarting apache.